# Dishwasher safe bakeware?

Tags: baking, cleaning

The few times I've placed a standard muffin pan (or other bakeware) in the dishwasher I've regretted it.  The pans end up with spots of rust remarkably quickly.

What kind of materials/finishes are susceptible to rust, and what's really safe?  I don't trust the vendors to be honest here: some of my rusty pans are non-stick 'dishwasher safe' models.

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13279/machine-washed-my-cake-pans

Comment: It's impossible for all-silicone bakeware to rust.

Answer (score 2):

### Materials you can put in the dishwasher

- **Glass**, both traditional and borax
- **Glazed ceramic**
- **Vitreous ceramic** (Luminarc)
- **Silicone**
- **Stainless steel**, if you don't leave it in there for days either before or after running the dishwasher.

### Materials you shouldn't put in the dishwasher

- anything with a **non-stick coating**
- aluminium and other **reactive metals** such as copper and cast iron. Not any kind of "tin" either, or black ?
- wood
- bamboo
- **unglazed ceramic** like earthenware

### Border cases

In general, you can put **enameled metal** in the dishwasher, but if you splurged on a LeCreuset and expect it to last for a lifetime, it is better to do it per hand too.

Another border case are **plastics**. There are some which will deform in the dishwasher and others which will be fine. Generally, the ones used in food vessels (such as tupperware food containers) and in utensils (such as high-melting-point nylon spatulas) are fine in the dishwasher.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where'd you pull this information from?  Seems like it might be a good candidate for a community post along with the commonly-referenced threads on food storage.

Comment: @logophobe I've known it for so long I forget where I learned it. I don't see the need for a community wiki here, but if you want to add something, suggest an edit and I'll probably accept it.