# Clarification needed on pots and pans in the dishwasher

Tags: equipment, cookware

So I know from a previous [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44801/dishwasher-safe-bakeware) that you are ok putting glass, glazed ceramics, silicone and stainless steel in the dishwasher, and that you should avoid putting non-stick coated, aluminium, copper, cast-iron, tin, wood, unglazed ceramics, etc in the dishwasher.

However, I'm in the market for a new set of pots and pans, and would like to know what I should be aiming for. At the moment, I have a skillet set:

- 4 inch non-stick - ruined
- 6 inch non-stick - ruined
- 8 inch non-stick - ruined
- 12 inch non-stick - not ruined
- 12 inch cast iron skillet - babied

During previous bouts of laziness, I've put them in the dishwasher and thus ruined the non-stick coating on most of them (the cast iron skillet is babied and never goes into the dishwasher). I also have a 14 quart pot, which is showing its age, and an 8 quart pot which had its bottom corroded to the point where a hole appeared (thus, leaky pot).

As an avid (and lazy when it comes to washing dishes) home cook, what should I be looking for in a set of pots and pans? At a minimum, what should I have in terms of sizes and types. I'd prefer to purchase them separately rather than buying a set (budget is not a limiting factor). Additionally, I'd love for them to be dishwasher safe, but I can add a few more 'hand wash only' items like my cast iron skillet.

**EDIT**

Per a comment below, [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/buying-my-first-set-of-pots-and-pans/) pretty much answers my question.

Comment: So you say you want a new set of pots and pans but then you talk about your set of skillets. Since you're looking to buy individual pieces, could you be more specific about what pieces you'd like to have? Also, have you looked at ScanPan? I have one of their 12 inch skillets and it's awesome. You can use metal tools on it but NOTHING sticks to it. They are also generally DW safe, though they recommend wiping clean and only DWing every 3-4th use.

Comment: Sorry, new commenting because I clearly can't read but I don't want to delete the previous comment to hide my shame. Maybe what would really help is knowing the number of people you're cooking for and what types of cooking you like to do.

Comment: @Catija - sorry, pots and pans includes skillets in my vocabulary :) I have not heard of ScanPan, but will look into it. As for number of people, typically my wife, my daughter and I. However, we do hold dinner parties that can balloon to 15 to 20 people. As to the type of cooking, everything would be putting it lightly (american, french, italian, hispanic, asian, mediterranean). We're very adventurous when it comes to food and what we cook every day (for instance, I baked a from-scratch mocha cake and cake-biscuits at 2am last night.)

Comment: @logophobe I saw that question when I was searching for questions similar to mine. While I did keep in mind that this question might raise the opinion-based flag, I hope it doesn't, as I'm not looking for specific "this is what you should get because I love it", rather "you might find skillets in x,y,z size, an x quart pot, and this other pan useful in your kitchen".

Comment: I think my advice still stands from an earlier, highly similar question : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/18272/67

Comment: @jsanc623 The killer words there are "might" and "useful".  Might in how many cases, and useful how?  You've added some helpful details by noting that you cook a lot of different cuisines, and sometimes for larger groups.  But this ultimately reduces down to "What cookware is flexible and easy to clean?" which sounds like it might devolve into a list of opinions.  Keep in mind - this is just my perspective.  Others may feel differently.  You can always ask in meta if you're not sure whether this would be on-topic.

Comment: @logophobe I totally understand now that you've pointed out 'might' and 'useful' amongst others. Perhaps I should simplify/reword my question. Though, the link that Joe posted pretty much answers my question to a T.

Comment: @jsanc623 I've closed this as a duplicate since you seem to be pretty happy with the old question. But if there are pieces you feel it doesn't answer, please please ask them! Notably your title makes it seem you're interested in knowing about putting pans in the dishwasher, which the other question definitely doesn't really answer.

Comment: Thank you @Jefromi. No further items left unanswered thankfully :)

Comment: Aha, there's also already a question about putting pots and pans in the dishwasher: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44807/pots-and-pans-in-the-dishwasher